# How to define someone who is more efficient than the actual person responsible for the task?

Tags: expressions, questions

Like we say "Holier than the pope" to define someone who acts more pious than the priest. I cannot recall expression for someone who acts over-efficiently over a matter than does not concern him that much.

Thanks

Comment: A self-appointed expert.

Comment: Do you mean someone who is actually better, or someone who just thinks they're better? Do you want a noun or an adjective or something else?

Comment: This is the normal state of things. The English language may lack a word for it because it's thoroughly unremarkable.